# Как правильно писать название продукта?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Мне нужно правильно написать предложение:
**Пюре со вкусом яблоко-тыква фирмы “Сады Придонья”.**
Нужно ли брать в кавычки слова "яблоко-тыква"?
Как называется такое построение названий в предложении? Возможно ли посмотреть в каком-нибудь учебнике?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примеры кавычки не нужны, т. к. "яблоко-тыква" не является названием продукта. Другое дело, если продукт имеет название, например: пюре "Фруто Няня". В таких случаях кавычки нужны по правилу.

Торговые названия продуктовых, парфюмерных и т. п. товаров, табачных изделий, марочных вин и других напитков заключаются в кавычки и пишутся с прописной буквы, напр.: сыр «Российский», колбаса «Докторская», конфеты «Ромашка», торт «Юбилейный», шоколад «Вдохновение», мыло «Детское», сигареты «Мальборо», вина «Солнечная долина», «Бычья кровь», «Монастырская изба», портвейн «Айгешат», напиток «Фанта».

См.: [Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина, § 199.](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=92#pp92)

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае несклоняемое составное слово обозначает *условную разновидность продукции* отдельной компании. В рамках рекламного слогана возможно любое написание: написанное без кавычек предполагает, что для потребителя это "родное" понятие (он якобы любит и знает продукцию этой фирмы). В нормальной же письменной речи нужно как-то обратить внимание читателя на факт *условности* (нет сложного слова "яблоко-тыква" - это указывает на несуществующий гибридный плод - и нет общепринятого понятия одноимённого вкуса) - **кавычки** с этим справляются. За пределами фирменных описаний и рекламных материалов то же самое было бы выражено словами "*со вкусом яблок и тыквы*" (*с яблочно-тыквенным вкусом*) или "яблочно-тыквенное пюре" (если продукт натуральный). Применяется и другой спрособ обозначения того же "вкуса" - другой фирмой. Он записывается в числе характеристик товара как "**Вкус: яблоко, тыква**".

Comment: "...Нет сложного слова "яблоко-тыква" - это указывает на несуществующий гибридный плод.." - это как понять?

Comment: Александр, зачем вдаваться в дебри? Это ведь не наименование. Зачем тут кавычки? Кавычки тут абсолютны не нужны.

Comment: Бывает вкус яблока, вкус тыквы, а также вкус яблока и тыквы - все нормальные ссылки на вкус склоняются, а здесь предлагается обозначение, которое грамматически не согласуется с другими членами предложения - это само по себе требует дополнительных средств типа кавычек.

Comment: Александр, несклоняемость - еще не повод для кавычек. Да и зачем в одном предложении нагромождать кавычки? Что здесь дадут кавычки?

Comment: Дефис и так указывает на гибрид.

Comment: Если допустить, что гибридный плод существует, то для ссылки на его вкус такое название пришлось бы склонять: без склонения выражение вкуса выглядит странно - так же странно, как "вкус яблоко" или "вкус тыква".

Comment: @ Alex_ander, вы правы, лучше склонить название, тогда и вопрос о кавычках отпадет.

Comment: И еще: у автора, по-видимому, ошибка. Надо писать: пюре со вкусом яблоки и тыквы. Потому что на упаковке этой фирмы нарисованы яблоко и тыква.

Answer (score 0):

1) **Варианты  названий**: **(1) Пюре из яблок и тыквы. (2) Пюре фруктовое яблоко-тыква.** Первое слово пишется с прописной буквы. Существует сложное слово "яблоко-тыква", и оно входит **в составное имя собственное.**

Можно усложнить название, указав торговую марку: **Пюре фруктовое яблоко-тыква  фирмы "Сады Придонья".**

Примечание. **Непонятно, что такое вкус яблоко-тыква**, это только их вкус, не натуральный продукт? Если всё-таки вкус, то: Пюре со вкусом "яблоко-тыква" фирмы “Сады Придонья”. В этом варианте желательны **кавычки** (с выделительной функцией).

**2) В обычных текстах** слово "пюре" уже не является в названием,  например:   Сладкая тыква, входящая в состав **пюре яблоко-тыква** фирмы «Сады Придонья», отличается тем, что прекрасно усваивается. Не содержащее сахара фруктовое **пюре из тыквы и яблок** фирмы «Сады Придонья» обладает не только приятным вкусом и нежной консистенцией.

3)  **Пюре Сады Придонья Яблоко-тыква**. А вот это уже неправильная запись.

Comment: Sibylla, не совсем понятно: чем отличается вкус от натурального продукта? В каких текстах "пюре' может входить в наименование?  Яблоко-тыква ведь не входит в наименование продукта, зачем кавычки?

Comment: Есть такие термины, как усилитель вкуса, заменитель вкуса, вкусовые добавки, ароматизаторы, в том числе синтетические. Например, существует пищевая эссенция с названием "Дюшес", которую  используют для приготовления теста и различных кондитерских изделий. Поэтому "пюре со вкусом"  может отпугнуть потребителя.

Comment: О кавычках. Названия могут иметь разные формы написания в зависимости от влияния различных факторов, в том числе от стиля речи. Можно выделить такие формы: 
1. Прописная буква, без кавычек (в специальной литературе). 
2. Прописная буква с кавычками.
 3. Строчная буква с кавычками.
 4. Строчная буква без кавычек.  Например: собака болонка, но клубника "виктория". Две первые формы - это имена собственные, а две вторые формы - это род+вид.

Comment: Да, вы правы, но в такие тонкости вдаваться не надо. Название лучше склонить, чтобы все вопросы отпали. Пюре со вкусом яблоки,тыквы. Кстати, здесь речь идет именно о вкусе. Так как на упаковке нарисованы яблоко и тыква.